# SVG маска для изображения (clip path css)

Tags: css3, svg, изображения, clip-path

помогите найти маску SVG, чтобы с помощь clip path и css сделать прямоугольное изображение вот таким, важно именно то, чтобы все углы были острые как на картинке, размеры этого блока могут быть произвольными, но шаг волны всегда одинаков[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой пример, но не подходит - https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем нарисовал контур (как в примере) и патерном поместил фото и рястянул - собствено дэмо

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 447.63491 248.40051">
  <defs>
    <pattern
       id="pattern"
       patternTransform="matrix(0.67788443,0,0,0.35518436,336.70444,366.21677)"
       height="1068"
       width="1141.3332"
       patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image
         y="5.884182e-015"
         x="-3.0433989e-014"
         id="image857"
         xlink:href="https://cs2.livemaster.ru/storage/54/32/fc870a3aa706ff4f4a05930e7dcv--odezhda-plate-bolshie-tsvety.jpg"
         preserveAspectRatio="none"
         height="1068"
         width="1141.3333" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <g
     transform="translate(216.85431,1.6998068)">
      <path
         d="m -181.65379,242.88934 c -11.51211,-3.17704 -13.93065,-3.22999 -23.42124,-0.5128 -4.09789,1.17324 -7.82106,1.82197 -8.2737,1.44165 -0.45264,-0.38034 0.35672,-4.22433 1.79858,-8.54218 2.52597,-7.5644 2.50168,-8.17681 -0.66611,-16.79455 -4.069,-11.0694 -4.06745,-12.05043 0.0369,-23.40451 l 3.32457,-9.19693 -3.61822,-10.52145 -3.61822,-10.52145 3.61822,-10.52144 3.61821,-10.52145 -3.32457,-9.19693 c -4.10502,-11.35593 -4.10633,-12.33392 -0.0315,-23.41907 l 3.29302,-8.95842 -3.56886,-10.531632 c -3.56782,-10.52856 -3.568,-10.53421 -0.61909,-19.292911 3.68578,-10.94731 3.68719,-14.509 0.0101,-25.42839 -2.93922,-8.72806 -2.9391,-8.73149 0.65384,-19.18229 l 3.59354,-10.45267 -3.16167,-8.5989503 c -1.73893,-4.7294296 -2.95711,-8.78404959 -2.70708,-9.01026959 0.25003,-0.22621 5.59549,0.90075 11.87879,2.50436999 l 11.42419,2.91567 12.52592,-3.04123 12.52592,-3.04122999 12.46611,3.02670999 12.46611,3.02671 12.688,-3.03562 12.68799,-3.03561999 12.46489,3.02640999 12.464881,3.02642 12.46489,-3.02642 12.46489,-3.02640999 12.687993,3.03561999 12.68799,3.03562 12.46612,-3.02671 12.46611,-3.02670999 12.52592,3.04122999 12.52593,3.04123 11.10848,-2.83509 c 13.70544,-3.4979 14.24704,-3.49729 27.28284,0.0305 l 10.58889,2.86558 12.87611,-3.08063 12.87611,-3.08062999 12.50281,3.03562999 12.502806,3.03562 12.55747,-3.0044 12.55747,-3.00438999 12.55747,3.00438999 12.55748,3.0044 12.50281,-3.03562 12.50281,-3.03562999 12.89357,3.08480999 12.89358,3.08481 10.06611,-2.74993 c 5.53637,-1.51245999 10.06612,-2.56889999 10.06612,-2.34764999 0,0.22125 -1.42149,4.26931999 -3.15887,8.99570959 -3.1577,8.5903203 -3.15771,8.5964703 -0.0203,17.0065403 3.92585,10.52349 3.93413,14.19786 0.0562,24.91403 -3.08359,8.52125 -3.08354,8.60667 0.0126,17.34055 3.87563,10.93478 3.86603,14.296231 -0.071,24.849791 -3.14099,8.419702 -3.14098,8.421212 0.0203,17.340542 3.92791,11.08227 3.92556,14.41551 -0.0176,24.98545 -3.13741,8.41007 -3.13739,8.41622 0.0203,17.00654 1.73737,4.72639 3.15886,10.25396 3.15886,12.28348 -1.68823,23.67944 -9.70224,54.02037 -3.22516,71.55924 1.70388,4.60002 2.91283,8.51921 2.68657,8.70931 -0.22626,0.19012 -4.97995,-0.82157 -10.56375,-2.2482 -12.67299,-3.23789 -13.53974,-3.23211 -26.90669,0.17939 l -10.94542,2.79348 -12.52175,-3.04022 -12.52176,-3.04022 -12.5954,3.05811 -12.5954,3.0581 -12.46488,-3.02641 -12.46488,-3.02642 -12.614766,3.0181 -12.61477,3.0181 -10.98293,-2.80304 c -13.5107,-3.4482 -13.63417,-3.44816 -27.79839,0.0106 l -11.52199,2.81305 -11.02208,-2.81305 c -6.06267,-1.54777 -12.21962,-2.81365 -13.68264,-2.81365 -1.46302,0 -7.61997,1.26588 -13.68212,2.81305 l -11.02208,2.81303 -11.52199,-2.81305 c -14.2141,-3.47031 -14.65469,-3.46962 -27.63518,0.0431 l -10.554323,2.85623 -12.78017,-3.10297 -12.78016,-3.10291 -12.728471,3.09041 -12.72848,3.09041 -11.76486,-3.10022 -11.76487,-3.10025 -10.53762,2.44085 c -15.2971,3.54329 -17.4212,3.59806 -27.85631,0.71824 z"
         style="fill:url(#pattern);" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо больше, не подскажешь где рисуются эти svg контуры? Photoshop, Illustrator?

Comment: Это сделано в inkscape

Comment: @Ubuntu User Грамотный подход, хороший ответ (+) Немного правый, нижний угол  не дорисован - слишком большая волна и некоторые переходы между волнами получились острыми. Нужно было поставить для этих узловых точек в Inkscape - "Сделать выделенные узлы автоматически сглаженными"

Comment: @Alexandr_TT да вроде бы полная копия - хотя может быть что то я не дорисовал - меня только бесят трансформации но в целом inkscape гененрирует код на много хуже чем тот же corel draw или illustrator но зато inkscape умеет то что не умеют они оба вместе - но хотелось бы узнать как избегать трансформаций именно в этой программе

Comment: @Ubuntu User  трансформации возникают, когда перемещаешь, поворачиваешь, увеличиваешь объект в Inkscape. Тррансформаций не будет, если рисовать "пером" сразу в нужном месте холста и не трансформировать изображение.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я проверю но похоже на правду....спсибо за полезный совет